# How to display multiple routes in one page using Ember js?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm stuck with an issue that I cannot solve. I have two routes - home and lhstree. When /home is called, I need both the routes to be rendered ie. lhstree should be rendered within home template. For this purpose, I used named `outlet`. That worked fine. 
But the problem is, I need to supply data to the lhstree template. But the model hook for the lhstree template is never called. I even tried adding alert messages in the model hook, but that too is never executed. The below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('home');
 this.route('lhstree');
});
```

home.hbs:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Home hbs rendering
    {{outlet 'lhstree'}}
</body>
</html>
```

home.js:

```
export default Route.extend({
    renderTemplate:function()
    {
        this.render();
        this.render('lhstree',{outlet:'lhstree',into:'home'});
    }
});
```

lhstree.hbs:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |player|}}
    <li>{{player}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

lhstree.js:

```
model() //THIS MODEL IS NEVER CALLED
{
  return ['Player1', 'Player2'];
}
```

As I mentioned, the model hook of lhstree route is never called. So, the player names Player1 and Player2 are never displayed when home template is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [rendering a template](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/rendering-a-template/) you can only set a template to an `outlet`, not a route. Therefore, in your case lhstree.hbs is called but lhstree.js route will not be called. If you want to pass data to the template in your outlet, you can call set the data in your home route. You can take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5e4924ae690e7cf3b06f007596466efc?openFiles=routes.home.js%2C&route=%2Fhome).

Comment: Hey Ahmet, your solution works. But what if I have to pass data to both home and lhstree templates?

Comment: @GiridharanJ I have updated the twiddle according to your comment. Now the home route model provides data to both home and lhstree templates.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two different ways to approach this problem:

1. If lhstree is ALWAYS going to be on the home page, don't use a route for it.  You could build it as a component, and pass attributes down to it from the parent (so get the data you need for lhstree in the Home model route).  So your outlet would be replaced by:

   ```
   {{lhstree-component model=model.lhsStuff}}
   ```
2. Make lhstree a sub route of Home.  That way when someone goes to home/lhstree Ember will render the lhstree template into the outlet within the Home template, and will call both models.  To do this, set up your routes like:

   ```
   Router.map(function() {
     this.route('home', function() {
       this.route('lhstree');
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Hey Morgan, thanks for your answer. I tried your second solution and it worked. Both the templates get rendered when I visit home/lhstree. But the problem is, I need both home and lhstree templates to be rendered when the user visits /home. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if this is best practise, but I would approach this by making lhstree a component.  Then you can use it in the Home template and pass it what it needs.  If you also want an lhstree route, make an lhstree template to be used by that route, and use the lhstree component in that template too